pyasn decoder.decode causing memory leak as docker stats show continuous memory grow (pysnmp=4.4.12 and pyasn1=0.4.8)
Intent is to get securityEngineId by decoding SNMP v3 trap using pysnmp but when SNMP traps are continuously coming then memory usage of application reach the docker containers memory limit after some time and if memory is increased then it again starts to increase
gc.collect() was tried to manually collect but as it doesn't guarantee the memory to be freed, memory continue to grow till container limit is reached (checked using docker stats command)
Any idea on what could be causing this memory issue?
Below Code is the main part where decoding is happening:
  if int(msg_version) == 3:
        msg, rest_of_whole_msg = decoder.decode(wholeMsg, asn1Spec=v3Message())
        security_parameters = msg.getComponentByPosition(0)
        security_parameters, rest = decoder.decode(
                security_parameters, asn1Spec=UsmSecurityParameters()
            )`

UPDATE (29/May/2024): The issue seems to be pysnmp as we are using pysnmp to decode and validate traps from particular agent. Removing this code didn't helped and only seeing issue for v3 traps.
Expectation is to have app reach a certain memory which is used at start-up and some for traps processing and stop increasing linearly.

Addressing memory issues requires a combination of optimizing your code, proper resource management, and using profiling tools to identify and fix leaks. By implementing these strategies, you should be able to stabilize the memory usage of your application and prevent it from growing uncontrollably

Please include an example showing how to implement these suggestions.

Anyone with the examples or explanation why it could be happening?

It seems that the memory leaks in pysnmp are due to not popping the objects from the cache.
In pysnmp/proto/secmod/rfc3414/service.py, the objects are pushed in the cache as follows:
# 3.2.2
msgAuthoritativeEngineId = securityParameters.getComponentByPosition(0)

securityStateReference = self._cache.push(
    msgUserName=securityParameters.getComponentByPosition(3)
)

and then, the objects will be popd here:
            # 7.2.6.a.1
            scopedPdu = scopedPduData.getComponent()
            contextEngineId = scopedPdu.getComponentByPosition(0)
            contextName = scopedPdu.getComponentByPosition(1)

            self._cache.pop(securityStateReference)

However, the objects will not be popped in some error cases. For example, the following is such a case:
        else:
            debug.logger & debug.FLAG_SM and debug.logger(
                'processIncomingMsg: will not discover EngineID')
            
            # free securityStateReference XXX
            raise error.StatusInformation(
                errorIndication=errind.unknownEngineID)

I think pysnmp should pop the objects properly at the following lines.
% diff service.py.old service.py
726a727
>                     self._cache.pop(securityStateReference)
740a742
>                     self._cache.pop(securityStateReference)
789a792
>                     self._cache.pop(securityStateReference)
805a809
>                 self._cache.pop(securityStateReference)


Thanks for the response, we can try it but if traps are processed successfully by pysnmp then memory should not increase linearly right?

I believe that even in the case of success, the self._cache is not cleared after the following code:
# 3.2.11 (moved up here to let Reports be authenticated & encrypted)
self._cache.pop(securityStateReference)  
securityStateReference = self._cache.push(
    msgUserName=securityParameters.getComponentByPosition(3),

The self._cache should be emptied after executing the above code.

You are correct.
In our case, it did not  increase if the traps were processed successfully.

Regarding your second comment, I think the object will be popped on the caller side.
The pushed object you mentioned will be passed to the caller by return (, , , , securityStateReference) or raise error.StatusInformation(securityStateReference=securityStateReference,) .
And then, it will be popped by smHandler.releaseStateInformation(securityStateReference) for example.
So, I think the object should be popped explicitly if it raises an error without passing securityStateReference in the error.StatusInformation().
At this point of view, my previous patch was insuffcient.

In our case, it is increasing even if all the traps are processed successfully.

Did you try it with the latest pysnmp and pyasn1 ? pysnmp 6.1.2 and pyasn1 0.6.0 are the latest.

Yes, tried with pysnmp-lextudio==6.1.2, pyasn1==0.6.0 and pyasn1-modules==0.4.0 as well.
